# How to label 5 specific points on PCA plot

Tags: r, label, pca, point

I have used package (`tidyverse`) and just wanted to add labels to 5 specific points on this lot. I have tried the below code but it is not giving me any points. the data set is about 2000 observations over 21 variables.

```
BOTTOM=which(interest2$ID%in%project.pca$ID); 
text(which(interest2$ID%in%project.pca$ID)[BOTTOM,1], text(which(interest2$ID%in%project.pca$ID))[BOTTOM,2],text(which(interest2$ID%in%project.pca$ID)[BOTTOM,3],rownames(input)[BOTTOM],pos=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With ggplot, Make the PCA plot first, and the add edition layer with dataframe with only those 5 points. Check out in this post for example

https://datavizpyr.com/how-to-add-labels-to-select-points-with-ggrepel/

Comment: Hi, it does not seem to recognise ggrepel in R even after installing the tidyverse and ggplot packages